# Pushing to DEV server using a post receive hook works great - but then can't commit remote changes

Tags: git, git-post-receive

Very new to git and after a bit of reading have setup the following workflow:

- Github repo
- Local repos (workstation and laptop)
- Dev Server - post receive hook pushes from a bare repo to the directory where files are served

This has been working great but today I wanted to commit changes made on the dev server, then pull them back locally.

But when I tried to stage and commit the changes I received the error: "fatal: Not a git repository..."

I think I understand why (because the the directory containing all the files isn't the git repo) but how would I go about committing changes on the DEV server and pulling them back locally?

Any help would be much appreciated - I'm a designer so you might have to explain this simply sorry.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if your setup is a good idea - it's cheap to have more clones, and avoid doing anything weird.

Edit: Previously I'd suggested the `--git-dir` option, but that won't work, since the repo is still bare, and Git knows it. You could work around it with some hackery, but the best thing is probably to make a non-bare clone, copy the changed files into it, commit, and push back. You could save yourself the trouble in the future by actually having a full repo where you need it.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'd only set it up that way because, well, that was the only info I could find on how to set up a workflow where you could push to a remote server. I'm a designer using the Tower GUI so not super confident with the command line - how would you set it up?

Answer (score 0):

To commit anything into `Git`, it needs to be a git repository.

Clone the git repository into the server from where you are serving, instead on ftp, sftp, rsync or one of the other similar alternatives you may be using, and for each update do a `git pull`

That way, you can commit from the server and push to github.

Git pull is very optimal and even reduces the amount of data that needs to be transferred to your server. Not just that, it is always a good idea to have the git repo on your server, as you can switch branches, tags and move to any point of time in history with a single command, in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial that might explain how to se all this up?I've just been struggling to find anything that explains a Git local dev, DEV server and LIVE server workflow that I understand - they all seem to assume a bit of knowledge.